# ¿Es correcto escribir "querría" en vez de "quería" para el condicional del verbo "querer"?

Tags: ortografía, pronunciación, conjugación

[SpanishDict](https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/querer) dice que la conjugación correcta de "querer" en el **condicional** en las formas de la primera y tercera persona singulares es **querría**, la cual sería regular. Pero jamás la he visto, solo he visto "quería", sin la segunda "r", como la conjugación del imperfecto. He visto "quería" usada como la primera o la tercera persona singular del condicional, y no solo en el imperfecto. Fue en los redes sociales, entonces no fue una situación muy formal. ¿Cuál es la forma correcta? ¿Cómo se pronuncia, con "r" o con "rr"?

Me parece que "querría" es correcta, pero quiero saber **si alguien usa querría realmente**.

Comment: Buenas, H Huang, bienvenido al sitio. He editado tu pregunta y te he corregido pequeñas discordancias de género y he añadido el signo de apertura de interrogación "¿".

Comment: Los había visto mucho en los días pasados, pero, por supuesto, cuando los busco, no encuentro nada...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El verbo querer es un verbo irregular y efectivamente **querría** se corresponde con la primera y la tercera personas del singular del condicional simple

> yo querría
>  él/ella querría

Siguiendo [este enlace](https://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/modelos-de-conjugacion-verbal#n49) puedes constatar esa afirmación en un fuente más canónica, el Diccionario de la Real Academía Española de la Lengua.

Es una forma perfectamente válida y usada en español. Quizás el ejemplo más común de su uso es:

- El [condicional de cortesía](https://www.gramaticas.net/2016/09/el-condicional-de-cortesia.html). Se emplea para solicitar algo de una forma más educada y respetuosa. Por ejemplo si vas a una tienda a comprar el producto X y el dependiente te pregunta si puede ayudarte, puedes responderle

> **Querría** dos paquetes de X, por favor.

Cierto es que en el mismo contexto también se pueden emplear otras formas del mismo verbo

> **Quería** dos paquetes de X, por favor
>   **Quisiera** dos paquetes de X, por favor

He encontrado [este hilo](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=34900) de discusión donde Ignacio Frías cita a la mencionada Academia de la Lengua:

> Me parece que la cuestión está muy bien resuelta en el *Esbozo de una
>   nueva gramática de la lengua española*, publicado por la Real Academia
>   en 1977. En § 3.14.9. f se lee:
>  El **condicional se emplea también como
>   expresión de cortesía** cuando anunciamos una pregunta o un ruego, o
>   manifestamos una volición: Me gustaría verlo otra vez.
>
> De igual manera que *Deseaba hablar con usted* o *Quería pedirle un favor*
>   (imperfecto de cortesía) se sienten como más amables que los presentes
>   *deseo* y *quiero*, los condicionales *desearía* y ***querría*** refuerzan la
>   modestia de la expresión y hacen más patente nuestra sumisión a la
>   voluntad de la persona a quien nos dirigimos.
>
> Nótese, p. ej., la gradación expresiva de estas preguntas:
>  ¿Desea
>   usted un género de mejor calidad?
>
> ¿Deseaba usted un género de mejor calidad?
>
> ¿**Desearía** usted un género de mejor calidad?

Quizás "quería" se emplee más que "querría" en este contexto porque es más fácil de pronunciar incluso para un nativo. La doble rr se pronucia igual que la r que aparece al comienzo de una palabra. Es el mismo sonido que en río, reir, rubio, ... etc.

Puedes constatar que la palabra "querría" se sigue usando si consultas [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=querr%C3%ADa&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquerr%C3%ADa%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cquerr%C3%ADa%3B%2Cc0) o [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=querr%C3%ADa).

Te copio algunos de los ejemplos que aparecen en esta segunda búsqueda donde podemos apreciar otro de los empleos del modo condicional: expresar posibilidad o deseo

> **Querría** verte más sereno, **querría** que no vivieras siempre con la sensación de que te falta algo, como le ha pasado a tu padre
>   ¿Quién **querría** vivir en un mundo sin magia?
>   Y yo no **querría** que ninguno de mis hijos se perdiese

Puedes reemplazar en esos ejemplos la forma "querría" por "desearía" que es la forma condicional del verbo desear. Pero NO puedes reemplazarla en este caso por *quería* con una sola r, pues las frases ya no expresarían deseo sino que la acción ha ocurrido en el pasado.

@aparente001 apunta otro uso de esta forma condicional en conjunción con el verbo decir

> querría decir = significaría

Esta forma se emplea cuando queremos explicar el significado de una cosa. Nótese que la equivalencia aplica cuando el sujeto NO es una persona. Es común que el sujeto en este caso sea "esto" o pueda sustituirse por dicho pronombre.

Comment: +1.  ¿Querrás agregar este ejemplo?  *querrá decir* = *significaría*

Comment: @aparente001 No tengo problema en agregarlo pero quizás confunda más que ayudar, ¿no? Ya que se trata de una forma verbal de querer, "querrá", que no ha comentado el OP.

Comment: Ah, me expresé mal, quería decir *querría decir = significaría*.  Pero tú decides, es tu post.

Comment: @aparente001 Lo he añadido pero creo que es meterse en una complicación nueva. NO siempre "querría decir" es igual a "significaría", pero bueno ...

Answer (score 2):

You're right, *quería* is actually the imperfect conjugation of *querer* in the *yo* and *él/ella/Ud.* form, while *querría* is the conditional form.

You'll find that in the majority of cases, instead of saying *querría,* speakers tend to use *quisiera* to mean "I would like." *Querer* (along with *poder* and *deber*) is conjugated in the subjunctive imperfect when we want to say "would __".

That would explain why you've only seen *quería,* which is used pretty frequently, and how you pretty much never see *querría.*

Answer (score 0):

*Supplementary answer*

I had never heard this, but on the internet I discovered that some people use **quedría** in place of **querría**.  This might partially account for your not having come across *querría*.  (But the main reason is that it is indeed used less often than other conditionals.)

Examples:

> Quedría saber si el jacuzzi exterior es de agua caliente.  ([fuente](https://www.tripadvisor.com.mx/FAQ_Answers-g667510-d596558-t1684486-Quedria_saber_si_el_jacuzzi_exterior_es_de_agua.html))
>
> Cubia quedría decir "junto al rio" y de ahí el nombre. (https://cubiagrado.jimdo.com/origen-del-nombre-del-pueblo/)

Comment: Curious. Maybe an analogy with *tendría*?

Comment: ¿Un comentario de un "anónimo" en una página de viajes es una fuente?

Comment: @DGaleano - No voy a buscar una fuente rigurosa para un error.  Encontré muchos ejemplos en el internet que constan que este error existe.  Los ejemplos los escogí solo para mostrar frases posibles.